# File extension - c#

Tags: c#

I have a directory that contains jpg,tif,pdf,doc and xls. The client DB conly contains the file names without extension. My app has to pick up the file and upload the file. One of the properties of the upload object is the file extension.

Is there a way of getting file extension if all i have is the path and name

eg:

C:\temp\somepicture.jpg is the file and the information i have through db is

c:\temp\somepicture

Comment: What happens if `C:\temp` contains both `C:\temp\somepicture.jpg` and `C:\temp\somepicture.tif`? Which file should `C:\temp\somepicture` refer to?

Comment: Donut- I have been assured that the names will be unique and oping that they would be..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could obtain a list of all of the files with that name, regardless of extension:

```
public string[] GetFileExtensions(string path)
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = 
        new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

    return directory.GetFiles(
        System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + ".*")
        .Select(f => f.Extension).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Directory.GetFiles(fileName + ".*")`.  If it returns just one file, then you find the file you need.  If it returns more than one, you have to choose which to upload.

Comment: If the DB has only file name w/o extension and if GetFiles() return anything other than one file (more than one file or no file), you should throw an exception.

Comment: @Partha Choudhury, what do do when GetFiles() returns multiple files is a business decision, not a technical one.  It's not appropriate to just blanket throw an exception always.  Depends on the specific business rules.

Comment: I like one method-one unit of work philosophy and hence would create a GetFullPathName(DB.FileNameWithouExtension) that returns a file name with full path and extension. If it cannot return one file name because it either got no file or more than one file, then it should throw an exception with relevant info ("no files found" or list of file names found) available in the exception instance to the caller so that the caller can determine what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```
DirectoryInfo D = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (FileInfo fi in D.GetFiles())
{
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName) == whatever)
        // do something
}
```

Comment: You don't want to iterate through all files in the directory when you know part of the file you're looking for.  Use a pattern filter when calling `GetFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, if you have no other information and there are 2 files with the same name and different extensions, you can't do anything (e.g. there is somepicture.jpg and somepicture.png at the same time).

On the other hand, usually that won't be the case so you can simply use a search pattern (e.g. somepicture.*) to find the one and only (if you're lucky) file.

Answer (score 0):

Search for files named somepicture.* in that folder, and upload any that matches ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the lowest level folder for each path.  For your example, you would have:
'c:\temp\'

Then find any files that start with your filename in that folder, in this case:
'somepicture'

Finally, grab the extension off the matching filename.  If you have duplicates, you would have to handle that in a unique way.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles() and iterate through all the filenames. You will run into issues when you have a collision like somefile.jpg and somefile.tif.

Sounds like you have bigger issues than just this and you may want to make an argument to store the file extension in your database as well to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: don't disagree, but if we're going down the path of theoretical data fixups, IMHO just keep the filename (with extension) in the database (use your new code to fix it up during your next upgrade? :) - if you want the parts back out, using System.IO.Path to do so is much nicer to me than doing storing the parts separately :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this perhaps....

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/temp/");
    FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("somepicture.*");
    foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
    {
        if(fi.Name.Contains("."))
        {
            string name = fi.Name.Split('.')[0].ToString();
            string ext =  fi.Name.Split('.')[1].ToString();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Extension is: " + ext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The string manipulation part of this needs work. Sample input: `C:\somefile v. 2.xls`

Comment: seconding Jon's comment, but for getting the parts, use the various static methods off of System.IO.Path - much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

One more, with the assumption of no files with same name but different extension.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", @"testasdadsadsas.*");

if (files.Length >= 1)
{
    string fullFilenameAndPath = files[0];

    Console.WriteLine(fullFilenameAndPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the crippled file path you can get the directory path and the file name:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
string name = Path.GetFileName(filename);
```

Then you can get all files that matches the file name with any extension:

```
FileInfo[] found = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles(name + ".*");
```

If the array contains one item, you have your match. If there is more than one item, you have to decide which one to use, or what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

All the pieces are here in the existing answers, but just trying to unify them into one answer for you - given the "guaranteed unique" declaration you're working with, you can toss in a FirstOrDefault since you don't need to worry about choosing among multiple potential matches.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var match = FindMatch(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("Best match for {0} is {1}", args[0], match ?? "[None found]");
}

private static string FindMatch(string pathAndFilename)
{
    return FindMatch(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathAndFilename), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathAndFilename));
}

private static string FindMatch(string path, string filename)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(path, filename + ".*").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Output:

```
> ConsoleApplication10 c:\temp\bogus
Best match for c:\temp\bogus is [None found]
> ConsoleApplication10 c:\temp\7z465
Best match for c:\temp\7z465 is c:\temp\7z465.msi
> ConsoleApplication10 c:\temp\boot
Best match for c:\temp\boot is c:\temp\boot.wim
```